# Optimization for recursive SQL Data reading

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, recursion, optimization, ado

I have a function that needs to check the current database values against the live data. Due to the way the database is set up, I need to run the function recursively, and it creates a new local ADO connection each time then deletes it when its finished. it is definitely slowing down my page. Assuming the SQL command is not the problem, is there a better way to obtain the database record (Faster) without establishing a new ADO record set connection each time?

**Here is my code/pseudo sample:**

```vb
Sub recursiveFunction()

    ~ run data validation ~ 

    Dim newObjRecordSet As Object = SysGlobals.CreateLocalObject()
    newObjRecordSet.Open(SQL_COMMAND,objConn, adOpenStatic ,adLockBatchOptimisti)

        Do Until newObjRecordSet.eof
            If (some condition) Then
                write()
            Else
                recursiveFunction()
            End If
            newObjRecordSet.MoveNext()
        Loop

    SysGlobals.DeleteLocalObject(newObjRecordSet)
End Sub
```

**Here are the global functions:**

```vb
Public Shared Function CreateLocalObject() As Object
    Dim localObj As New Object
    localObj = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    localObj.CursorLocation = ADORef.ADOVBS.adUseClient
    Return localObj
End Function

Public Shared Sub DeleteLocalObject(ByRef localObj As Object)
    If localObj.State() Then localObj.Close()
    localObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Any inputs would be appreciated!**

Comment: what kind of database are you using?

Comment: I would look at the system.data.sqlclient namespace.  You can open the connection as a class variable once then call your recursive function and close the connection when complete.  Also check out your connection string, ADO should be doing connection pooling by default so even if you close your connections they are really stored in a pool and reused.  Maybe your deleting the object is preventing the pooling...

Comment: - We are using MS Access DB
- OK, I need to research on "pooling" and ADO types.

Comment: In regards to pooling, 

Since some of those ADO are still in use while the new ones were being created, if i don't delete the current ADO it might trigger the "Object is still open" error?

Comment: With MS Access, sometimes the old ADO libraries provide better performance... but you tagged your question with sql-server and ado.net, mentioned ADO.NET in the title - you are unlikely to get meaningful responses starting out with that sort of confusion.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression they were the same. Is it safe to assume that ADO uses object to contain recordset and ADO.NET use sqldatareader to read one liners?